# Segmentation fault using python layer in caffe

Tags: python, caffe

I'm trying to use python layer as described [here](http://chrischoy.github.io/research/caffe-python-layer/).
But I am getting this exception:

```
I1007 17:48:31.366592 30357 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
*** Aborted at 1475851711 (unix time) try "date -d @1475851711" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7f32895f1156 (unknown)
*** SIGSEGV (@0x0) received by PID 30357 (TID 0x7f328b07fa40) from PID 0; stack trace: ***
@     0x7f328883ecb0 (unknown)
@     0x7f32895f1156 (unknown)
@     0x7f3289b43dfe (unknown)
@     0x7f32429d0d9c google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromArray()
@     0x7f3242a1f652 google::protobuf::EncodedDescriptorDatabase::Add()
@     0x7f32429da012 google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile()
@     0x7f3242a2b33e google::protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto()
@     0x7f3242a5aa75 google::protobuf::StaticDescriptorInitializer_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto::StaticDescriptorInitializer_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto()
@     0x7f3242a56beb __static_initialization_and_destruction_0()
@     0x7f3242a56c00 _GLOBAL__sub_I_descriptor.pb.cc
@     0x7f328aeca10a (unknown)
@     0x7f328aeca1f3 (unknown)
@     0x7f328aecec30 (unknown)
@     0x7f328aec9fc4 (unknown)
@     0x7f328aece37b (unknown)
@     0x7f327d91b02b (unknown)
@     0x7f328aec9fc4 (unknown)
@     0x7f327d91b62d (unknown)
@     0x7f327d91b0c1 (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f412ae (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f09dae (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f88729 (unknown)
@     0x7f3288ebccbf (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f81d66 (unknown)
@     0x7f3288e47a3f (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f12d43 (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f8b577 (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f6dc13 (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f7154d (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f71682 (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f71a2c (unknown)
@     0x7f3288f88016 (unknown)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, GPU caffe installation. Python layer and prototxt are [here](https://gist.github.com//shelhamer/8d9a94cf75e6fb2df221).
Could anybody suggest anything? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: As described *where*?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Also, please summarize the environment.  What topology are you using?  What stack?  What hardware?  The CPU/GPU difference drives a lot of the software checks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the link. I added it.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this is one of the most prevalent weaknesses in Caffe: this SegFault without an error message.  I generally get this when I haven't connected the data layer properly.  For instance, I haven't started the data server, or there's a severe mismatch in format.